# Spring data rest: Can we rename the "content" property in pagination result?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have an endpoint which gives the results as paginated output like below.

Code Snippet:

```
public Page<MyObject> getData(Pageable pageable) {
    return repository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "",
            "regionName": "",
            "category1": "",
            "category2": "",
            "modifiedDateTime": "",
            "abstract": ""
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageSize": 1,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "last": false,
    "totalPages": 10,
    "totalElements": 5808,
    "size": 1,
    "number": 0,
    "numberOfElements": 1,
    "first": true,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true
    }
}
```

Can we rename the property name "content" to a different name like "data"?

Also Can we remove the additional paging parameters in the output?
For eg: sort, offset

Comment: Hint from [I do ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) : could you please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have updated the question with code snippets

Answer (score 5):

You can't modify PageImpl class and add `@JsonProperty`s to rename but you can create a decorator for it. Also if you need to hide pageable (or any other properties) then you just don't expose them to decorator.

```
class PageDecorator<T> {

    private final Page<T> page;

    public PageDecorator(Page<T> page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data") // override property name in json
    public List<T> getContent() {
        return this.page.getContent();
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return page.getTotalPages();
    }

    public long getTotalElements() {
        return page.getTotalElements();
    }

    ... 
}
```

Your code shall look like:

```
public PageDecorator<MyObject> getData(Pageable pageable) {
    return new PageDecorator<>(repository.findAll(pageable));
}
```